# How do certain websites auto-complete my school name in forms?

Tags: forms, autocomplete

I suppose they can just wait for me to type the first letter and then a web-service can send me a list of schools starting with that letter. Is this normally how it is done?

Is there packages out there for this sort of auto-complete system? I suppose it would have to work with *similar phrases* and give you recommendations, unlike a tag system where the tag would be identical to what would be found in a table somewhere.

Comment: This would be a better question if you give examples.

Answer (score 0):

Probably combination/elements of browser settings, AJAX, JQuery to get think client behaviour with the thin client.  ASP AJAX controls certainly have this feature already baked in.